# Creating a new column based on another without throwing warning

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataFrame live (live births) with a column 'agepreg' which is a float with two decimal places. I'd like to create a new column 'agepreg_rounded' as integer.

My naive approach:

```
live['agepreg_rounded'] = live['agepreg'].apply(lambda x: round(x,0))
```

Does work, but throws warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

I've tried multiple times to use the .loc syntax, but failed.

Can anyone set me straight?

Here's the sort of thing I'm tempted to write, but that is clearly wrong:

```
live['agepreg_rounded'] = live.loc[live['agepreg']].apply(lambda x: round(x,0))
```

**Update: Where does live come from?**

I'm following ThinkStats2 book from O'Reilly and the data comes from a file downloaded with the source material:

```
import nsfg
preg = nsfg.ReadFemPreg()
live = preg[preg.outcome == 1]
```

Comment: What is your code above `live['agepreg_rounded'] = live['agepreg'].apply(lambda x: round(x,0))` ?

Comment: @jezrael Sorry I'm not sure if I've mis-understood your question, but this is my attempt at creating a new column based on 'agepreg' but without the decimal. I realise now that technically I'm not trying to turn it into an integer, just round it.

Comment: OK, how is created `live` ? Maybe help [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582)

Comment: @jezrael it gets created from a file from the book I'm following along. I've added a brief note to the question detailing this a little more.

Comment: so need `live = preg[preg.outcome == 1].copy()`

Comment: @jezrael ah I see. The problem was in a different place to where I thought it was. If only the warning had specified a line, think this might be related to the version of ipython I'm using though. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) and then instead `apply` use [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
live = preg[preg.outcome == 1].copy()
live['agepreg_rounded'] = live['agepreg'].round(0)
```

If you modify values in `live` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`preg`), and that Pandas does warning.

Comment: Thanks again! As soon as it lets me I shall tick this answer.

Comment: @goose - it is a bit not clear warning, because problem is in another row of code :(